# MySQL - Why is COUNT with "greater than" quick but "less than" takes forever?

Tags: mysql, count, performance, comparison-operators

```
SELECT count(*) c FROM full_view WHERE verified > ( DATE (NOW()) - INTERVAL 30 DAY)
```

If I run that query it takes a split second but if I switch the comparison operator around it takes eons. Now the first way the count = 0 and the second way the count = 120000, but if I just count the whole table that also takes microseconds.

But there is something something funky going on because if the query ever does finish it runs super quick thereafter. MySQL is caching the query or something right? Well, I don't want to depend on caches to make sure the website doesn't hang.

This seems nonsensical: if it can count everything greater than a certain date quickly, why should it take any longer to count the opposite? Either way it has to look through the whole table right? And all it needs to return is a number so bandwidth shouldn't be an issue.

Explain on the query:

```
1, 'SIMPLE', 'b', 'range', 'updated,verified_index', 'updated', '3', '', 28, 'Using where'`    
1, 'SIMPLE', 'l', 'eq_ref', 'PRIMARY', 'PRIMARY', '4', 'xyz_main.b.loc_id', 1, 'Using index'
1, 'SIMPLE', 'f', 'ALL', '', '', '', '', 2214, ''
```

---

EDIT:

This may be of some interest, I found this info when I run the query:

Handler_read_rnd_next:

- 254436689 (when doing less than)
- 2 (for greater than)

Key_read_requests:
314393 vs 33 (33 is the biggest number for all of the stats when using greater than)

Handler_read_key:
104303 vs 1

Bypassing the view and running the query directly on the main table eliminates the slowness. So what do I need to do to speed it up? The view is essentially like this:

```
SELECT x, y, z, verified FROM table1 LEFT JOIN table2 on tab2_ID = table2.ID LEFT JOIN table3 on tab3_ID = table3.ID
```

---

SOLVED:
Frankie led my in the right direction. The second joined table (the company table) was joined via the full text name of the companies. I only recently decided to add a integer key to that table. The name column was supposed to be indexed but I may have botched that. Anyway I re-organized everything. I converted the foreign key in the main table to match the integer ID of the company table rather than the full company name. I re-indexed those columns in each table, then I updated the view to reflect the new join point. Now it runs instantly in both directions. :) So I guess integer keys were the key. The problem is gone but still, I don't feel like my original question was really solved.

Thanks for your help guys.

Comment: I assume `full_view` is a view, what's the definition of that?

Comment: What does 'explain plan' tell you?

Comment: full_view contains the main table (with the verified column) left joined to two other tables. The main table is people and the other two tables join location and company info. It's pretty straight forward.

Comment: Can you perhaps try to do it out of the view? Just so we can see if anything changes? I'm off to bed. Gonna check on this tomorrow.

Comment: @Moss can we possibly get a DUMP of the data to play with the values?

Comment: @Moss I don't get... the last column on that `EXPLAIN` should return the number of rows mysql believes it must examine. Well... even on the worst case it goes at 2200 and that is very few...

Comment: Frankie you are on to something, just counting the main table is fast either way. I can't give you a dump, the data is confidential.

Comment: @Moss now I'm really tiered. Like I said will be back tomorrow. Edited my answer to give a clearer view of the `EXPLAIN` command. Perhaps the main problem is, in fact, in the view itself?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please run the bellow query and post the results.

```
EXPLAIN SELECT count(*) c 
FROM full_view 
WHERE verified > ( DATE (NOW()) - INTERVAL 30 DAY)
```

**The long forgotten [`EXPLAIN`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/explain.html) almost always brings something in! ;**)

---

**Edit 1:**
This is probably the offensive line:

```
1, 'SIMPLE', 'f', 'ALL', '', '', '', '', 2214, ''
```

The `ALL` there states that there is a FULL table scan.

You can dig further into the [**`Explain` syntax on this diagram**](http://www.pythian.com/news/wp-content/uploads/explain-diagram.pdf).

Do try to see where the differences go...

---

**Edit 2:**
[This doc will sure make things much clearer on the `Explain` output. Please check it out.](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/explain-output.html)

---

**Edit 3:**
Step-by-step analys of the explain command.

```
1, 'SIMPLE', 'b', 'range', 'updated,verified_index', 'updated', '3', '', 28, 'Using where'`    
1 - id
SIMPLE - simple select, not using sub-queries
b - table name
range - only rows that are in a given range are retrieved, using an index
updated,verified_index - are both possible keys
updated - was the key eventually used
3 - key lenght
'' - this is the ref column and would show which columns or constants are compared to the index name in the key column to select rows from the table.
28 - number of rows mysql believes it must examine to execute the query
Using where - self explanatory
```

Answer (score 2):

My guess is that the subtraction from the `Date(Now())` is what's taking a long time to process.  For values of `verified` that are already less than `Date(Now())`, the evaluation can be short-circuited because at that point it MUST be false (when comparing "greater than").

In the situation where you're comparing with "less than," the date time must be subtracted in every case, regardless of current value, since it has no way of logically concluding the expression to be true or false prior to evaluating the datetime subtraction

That's just a guess, though - take it with a grain of salt.

Comment: Using an explicit date also takes forever.

Comment: @Moss Interesting, maybe my idea is off-base then.  How about just reversing the order of the comparison?  Instead of `A < B`, do `B > A` and see if it takes as long - it should execute exactly the same (I would guess)

Comment: Interesting thought, but too late to try it now. I solved the problem with betters keys/indexing.

Answer (score 1):

It may be the case that there are statistics telling the database engine that there are no records for verified > 30 days ago.  In that case, it doesn't even have to read the table at all, but rather get info from the stats histogram.

Answer (score 0):

If you've an index on `verified` in the table then the more restrictive `COUNT` (the > one) will be quicker.  The COUNT(*) without a WHERE clause can return quickly as the count can be gleaned from table/index statistics.

Comment: Putting the comparison inside the count is nicer syntax but it doesn't speed it up. And I do have an index on `verified`.

Comment: In fact this method makes it slow in both directions.